# svg wont scale to full height, parent flex, flex-direction: column

Tags: css, svg, flexbox

this [codepen](https://codepen.io/Teiem/pen/KEjgJr) showes my setup. the svg should scale with the parent like it does when flex-direction is set to row.

I hope you can help me

```
 flex-direction: column;
```

Edit: copied the codepen code

```
<div class="grandparent">
<div class="parent">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="none" 
class="child" width="100%" height="100%">
  <line class="top" x1="0" y1="0" x2="300%" y2="0" />
  <line class="left" x1="0" y1="100%" x2="0" y2="-200%" />
  <line class="bottom" x1="100%" y1="100%" x2="-200%" y2="100%" />
  <line class="right" x1="100%" y1="0" x2="100%" y2="300%" />
</svg>
</div>
</div>


 .grandparent {
 height: 50vh;
 width: 50vh;

display: flex; 
flex-direction: column;
  }

 .parent {
  flex: auto;
 position: relative;
}

svg line {
   stroke-width: 3;
stroke: #000;
fill: none;
}
```

Comment: What is `flex:auto`? I think you want `flex:1`

Comment: flex: auto =   flex-grow: 1;
    flex-shrink: 1;
    flex-basis: auto;

Answer (score 1):

Use viewbox instead of height and width to scale the svg.

Example: viewbox="0 0 100 100".

https://css-tricks.com/scale-svg/

Comment: the square was just an example, because I have to set stroke-dasharray relative to the width and height